# Changing member variable of child entity changes it for all parent entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have an entity *object* which has a child entity *modification*. The *modification* has a date variable. I'm getting my *object*s this way:

```
return dbContext.Set<Objects>()
            .Include(x => x.modification)
            .ToList();
```

When updating an entity I want to set the date to *DateTime.Now*. But when doing this, all other objects, which have the same child entity, have *DateTime.Now* as date.

I want to change the DateTime only for the selected object. If the DateTime is already in the database the navigation property should point to this and if not it should create a new one. How is this possible?

I also have another example: The object has a *purchase* navigation property containing a net price. Changing this leads to a change in all other objects having the same navigation property with that net price. But changing the net price in one object should lead to a new navigation property without changing all other objects having the same property.

Comment: are the parent entities sharing a reference to the same child as opposed to a copy? sounds like the issue here

Comment: Yes in the db they have the same foreign key and in code they have the same child entity.